# Simplify quadratic polynomial with matrix

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

I am reading a [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:273847/FULLTEXT01.pdf&ei=fBZZU9yKAq2p7Aak6oDgBA&usg=AFQjCNGiCLyTpQy9FfdjVoDJSwGxH_lP0g&sig2=t8Fj4OWCw6XVf-fdGLrhaw&bvm=bv.65397613,d.ZGU) and have trouble following equation (3):

$$
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{d})^T \mathbf{A}_1 (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{d}) + \mathbf{b}^T_1 (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{d}) + c_1 = \\
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x} + (\mathbf{b}_1 - 2 \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{d})^T \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{d}^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{d} - \mathbf{b}^T_1 \mathbf{d} + c_1
$$
where $\mathbf{A}_1$ is symmetric.

What I get instead is (listing only the terms with $\mathbf{x}$) is for the first term:
$$
((\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{d})^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x} - (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{d})^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{d}) =\\
(((\mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x})^T \mathbf{x} - (\mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x})^T \mathbf{d}) - ((\mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{d})^T \mathbf{x} - (\mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{d})^T \mathbf{d}))^T = \\
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{d}^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{d}
$$
and for the second term:
$$
\mathbf{b}^T_1 \mathbf{x}
$$
so
$$
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{d}^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{d} + \mathbf{b}^T_1 \mathbf{x} + \dots
$$

Is this already wrong or is there some step from this to the solution that I can not see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summands like $\mathbf d^T\mathbf A_1\mathbf x$ are scalars. Every scalar (viewed as a $1\times 1$ matrix) is equal to its transpose. Thus we have $\mathbf d^T\mathbf A_1\mathbf x = (\mathbf d^T\mathbf A_1\mathbf x)^T = \mathbf x^T\mathbf A_1^T\mathbf d$ etc..

Comment: Thanks. And with $\mathbf{A}_1$ beeing symmetric it is clear.

Comment: @tauran Yes, you are right.